# Can adjuncts be put between a verb and its complement?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, adjuncts

> I think he knows **more or less** everything that goes on here, you know.
>   (Harry Potter)

I’ve heard, in English, adjuncts cannot be put between verbs and their complements. For instance:

> *I think he knows **usually** everything that goes on here.

If this is right, shouldn’t ‘more or less’ be put after ‘everything’?

Comment: *More or less* is a quantifier here: think of it as *more-or-less-every*

Comment: I think this is Too Localised. I don't know what *adjuncts cannot be put between verb-heads and their complements* is supposed to mean, but if it's in a context where "adjunct" includes adverbial terms like *more or less, almost, practically*, it's a totally worthless concept. If "adjunct" means something else, it just goes to show the terminology isn't worth bothering with.

Comment: I have edited this to make the issue clearer. I think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that adjuncts which modify *the verb* cannot be placed between the verb and its complements. But *more or less* in your example doesn't modify the verb. It modifies *everything*.

> More or less everything that goes on here is known by him.

Consequently it is a part of the complement, and the rule is not violated. In fact, it is the *determiner* of the NP which constitutes the complement, and as such it *must* go at the head of that constituent.